# Text on Group Theory and Graphs

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, graph-theory

A student and I are going to investigate the use of group theoretic techniques in graph theory. What are good texts in this area (introductory and otherwise)? We are particularly interested in studying automorphism groups of graphs, but a text with a broader view would also be welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just a few suggestions (for a survey see also [here](http://www1.cs.columbia.edu/~sanders/graphtheory/writings/books.html)):

W. Dicks and M. J. Dunwoody, Groups Acting on Graphs, Cambridge University Press, Cambridge, 1989.

C. Godsil and G. Royle. Algebraic Graph Theory. Graduate Texts in Mathematics vol. 207, Springer, New York, 2001.

N.L. Biggs. Algebraic Graph Theory. Cambridge Tracts in Mathematics 67, Cambridge University Press 1974 (2nd Edition 1993)

Answer (score 1):

Since Dietrich has already listed several nice books, I just add two more books to his list:

1. Trees, by J.P. Serre,
2. Groups, Graphs and Trees by John Meier.

Comment: I like both these books, but I don't think they are what the OP are after. They study groups using graphs rather than graphs using trees

Comment: @user1729: I see your point. But there are lots of interesting subjects in those books which relate graphs and groups. They have been very aspirational for me, so I suggested them hoping they would be useful for OP as well.