# Textbooks on graph theory

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, graph-theory, book-recommendation

I've read the textbook Groups and Their Graphs by Grossman, and I'm interested in learning more about graphs. I know about O. Ore's book in the same series (Graphs and Their Uses), but I'm interested in a book which will tell me more about the relation between graphs and groups.  I don't know any advanced mathematics (I only about group theory and graph theory from Grossman's book), so please recommend books which are not too complicated. I would also be glad for recommendations of books which are about group theory but have a focus on graphs.

Comment: Similar question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/694363/text-on-group-theory-and-graphs

Comment: I've looked at Godsil and Royd; and Biggs: they seem too advanced for me.

Comment: I have to mention that I have very little background in maths: I only know a little bit of (naive) set theory, and some geometry, algebra etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be interested in the book *Graphs, Groups and Trees* by John Meier. It is a very readable introduction to "geometric group theory", and is pitched at "advanced undergraduate" level (in the question linked in the comments, some of the books are graduate level and above). Geometric group theory can be interpreted as "the study of groups using their actions", and the simplest actions are actions on graphs. Hence, this book studies groups by using their actions *on graphs*.

Topics covered in the book include group actions, Cayley graphs (every group acts on a graph, and the Cayley graph is such a graph), actions on trees and basic Bass-Serre theory, the word problem for groups, regular lagnauges and normal form, and the coarse geometry of groups. There are lots  of examples to get your teeth into (every other chapter takes a specific group and analyses it using the previous chapter).

I should say that Meier's book assumes a working knowledge of group theory, but I would be surprised if there existed a book on this subject which did not!

---

@ABajaj The book you were reading, by Grossman and Magnus, was from the "new mathematical library". This "library" was a collection of books pitched at your level (US high school) which accompanied a new method of teaching maths (called [*new math*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_math)) in the US. The method was generally considered [a failure](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UIKGV2cTgqA&feature=kp), and therefore I would doubt if there was a set follow-on book. Meier's book perhaps requires a *small* jump from where you are just now, but this jump can most likely be helped by also buying an introductory group theory text to use as a reference. If you know what a normal subgroup is, then you are probably good to go! (The word "[Sylow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylow_theorems)" does not enter Meier's book, although enters every single "standard" group theory text, so your jump will not be too big!)

I should point out that the name of Magnus is a famous one in geometric group theory. So Meier's book, and geometric group theory in general, is a natural place to go next.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not an advanced undergraduate, or an undergraduate of any sort... right now. Currently I'm in senior secondary school(what is known as high school in the U.S.)

Comment: As for group theory, my knowledge  only goes as far as symmetric groups, permutation groups etc.

Comment: @ABajaj I have edited my post to respond to your comments. Basically, if you know what a normal subgroup is then you should be fine, but you might want to bring a "first course in group theory" text along as a reference (and I am sure that many people here will be willing to suggest their favorite such text).